# How to make a graph of a sum of a series of numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to make a graph that tracks the sum of a series of numbers. For example if I have the cells

| 5  |

| -3 |

| 8  |

| 7  |

| -4 |

I would like a graph that follows 5, 2, 10, 17, 13. How do I do this please? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try adding a new column with the following formula for graph purposes.

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SCAN(,A:A,LAMBDA(ini,ax,ax+ini)),ROW(LOOKUP(2^99, A:A)),1)`

- Column A has raw data and cell B1 accommodates the formula.

[image]